# python module call submodule method

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

It maybe easy or fool. But I hope not.

Things got to be wrong!

```
# This work
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker()

# This not: 'module' object has no attribute 'orm'
import sqlalchemy
Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker()
```

Why I want to use the second form? I use sessionmaker only once, I don't like to write a `from import` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method will only work iif there is a line `from . import orm` in `sqlalchemy/__init__.py` and it seems that it's not the case.

Alternatively you can `import sqlalchemy.orm` if you like explicit naming